# how can i iterate over all items before returning true

Tags: python, dictionary

im wondering if there is a way to iterate over all the keys before returning true. in this example if the update item['one] != old_item['one] it goes ahead and returns true without checking two.

```
unique_keys = ('one','two')

def check_if_items_change(old_item, new_item, unique_key):
    update_item = {**old_item,**new_item}
    for field in unique_keys:
        if update_item[field] != old_item[field]:
            return True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a flag and first set flag to `False` and after go to `if` set the flag to `True` and at the end return `flag`.

```
unique_keys = ('one','two')

def check_if_items_change(old_item, new_item, unique_key):
    update_item = {**old_item,**new_item}
    flag = False
    for field in unique_keys:
        if update_item[field] != old_item[field]:
            flag = True
    return flag
```